# nuget package for selenium webdriver MSEdgeDriver version 89.0 is missing linux binaries

Tags: linux, selenium-webdriver, nuget, microsoft-edge

I am using the following version of the webdriver. . .

Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver --version 89.0.774.54

My code was working well in macOS, but attempting the build the project in a Linux docker container fails for me. Upon further investigation, I saw that the nuget package does not have a folder for linux,

```
/root/.nuget/packages/selenium.webdriver.msedgedriver/89.0.774.54/driver:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr  7 10:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr  7 10:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  7 10:16 mac64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  7 10:16 win32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  7 10:16 win64
```

I do not see any Linux folder here. Also, the exact command that fails during a dotnet build is the following. . .

`chmod: cannot access  '/root/.nuget/packages/selenium.webdriver.msedgedriver/89.0.774.54/build/../driver//msedgedriver': No such file or directory`

apparently, the project restores step in the build is unable to locate the right driver. that // at the end of the path feels like the build process does not even know how to identify the correct driver folder (macOS/win32/win64) since Linux is not there.

How does one fix this?

Comment: I have verified that the Linux version of the driver exists for chrome, in the linux64 folder. so something is really missing

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the package folder and indeed it doesn't contain Edge driver for Linux.

I suggest that you can download Edge WebDriver for Linux directly on [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). Please note that not every version has Linux version, the latest version for Linux is 90.0.810.1. Another version for Linux I found is 88.0.692.0.

You can also try to find if there're other versions for Linux and find the one which is suitable for you. Then you can try to test Edge automation on Linux with that WebDriver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This really helped. I wonder why the Linux driver is not included in the first place in the NuGet package.  Also, seems like I'll have to go create a custom NuGet package to make sure that I have a consistent build..

Comment: About your concern, you can also open an issue or create a pull request in the package's [GitHub page](https://github.com/leandrodotec/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-msedgedriver).